# Part of WHILE in external file

Tags: php

Is it possible to run a while with each part in external files?

I mean:

INDEX.PHP

```
<?php
$x = 0;
require "PART1.PHP";
echo "Hello World<br>";
require "PART2.PHP"
?>
```

PART1.PHP

```
while($x<2) {
```

PART2.PHP

```
$x++;
}
```

And get as result

```
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

Comment: Try it and see.  In any case, this would make your life as a developer very difficult.  This sort of coding practice would be impossible to maintain.  What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: For sure I tried using require and include. 
Obviously I didn't get succes once I wouldn't be here asking (LOL).
I'd like to know if there's any way to do this.. any function like eval or something... 
And about the maintain.. I'm trying to get a function to avoid code repetition. Is for personal use only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible like you try it, since part1.php and part2.php do not contain valid php code for themselves. They contain only parts of code.

It will work, if you include parts of php in your files that make sense on their own and prepend them with an opening php-tag:

Main file:

```
<?php
$x=0;
echo "Hello World<br />";
require('part1');
```

part1.php:

```
WHILE($x < 2) {
    require('part2.php');
}
```

part2.php

```
<?php
echo "Hello World<br />";
$x++;
```

Comment: One more point: The $x++; should only be put in another file if it will be modified in different ways. If it's always only an increment for rounds of the loop it belongs in part1.php and part2.php will only contain the code that is executed within the loop.